# Make a full screen CSS background image appear "behind" a mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I've set an HTML/CSS full-screen background image with:

```
html, body {
  background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The background image looks good when viewed in a desktop browser or initially when viewed on a mobile browser. However, if I open the keyboard in the mobile browser then the image resizes to cover the space above the keyboard.

Instead of resizing, I'd like the image to appear to be "behind" the keyboard, and have the bottom portion of the image obscured. Avoiding resizing the image will make opening and closing the keyboard less jarring. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

I've tried setting the `document.body.style.backgroundSize` to the original window height after window resize events but that doesn't seem to impact the background image size at all.

Here are screen shots of the no-keyboard and keyboard-open states:

[image: No keyboard open] [image: Keyboard open]

Comment: Using `vh` is a good thought, but unfortunately it appears that the `vh` unit is calculated relative to the current viewport. When the keyboard opens the viewport shrinks, so I still have the same issue with the image resizing. This post explains a bit about the troublesome `vh` unit - https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/toolbars-keyboards-and-the-viewports-10abcc6c3769

Comment: @Michael Why don't you try the other way round of what @Rahul has mentioned. (i.e. `background-size: 100% auto;` since this way the image `width` will remain to 100% of the viewport, but `height` will be set to its default value, thus avoiding the resizing issue.

Comment: `background-size: 100vw auto;` is correct, the previous comment was just a typo. @AlokSingh, thanks for correcting it!

Comment: When you open the keyboard the "View port" size changes, it's like resizing your browser. that's why `background-size: 100vw auto;` works, probably your background position `center center;` should be `center top` to support landscape mode

Comment: Setting the height to `auto` unfortunately makes the image not "cover" correctly, so it only occupies the middle of the screen and doesn't fill the entire viewport, leaving white bars above and below it. I still need to emulate the "cover" behavior when the keyboard isn't open, and I'd like the keyboard-open background to _appear_ be the exact same size as the no-keyboard background image, and just partially obscured

Comment: @Michael Since  _it only occupies the middle of the screen and doesn't fill the entire viewport, leaving white bars above and below it_, it probably means the image is being stretched when used with `background-size:cover`, if this is true you will need to stretch your image accordingly to fit the screen size you are working on.

Comment: Yeah, `background-size: cover` is definitely scaling the image to fit the screen. However, I'm relying on that behavior to achieve a full-screen background image that works on many different screen sizes. This needs to look like a full screen image on desktop and mobile, no matter what the device size is.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem too, my problem solved with this

BEFORE :

```
background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

AFTER :

```
background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
```

just change `center` to `top`

Answer (score 1):

It took me forever to figure this out. The key being `background-attachment:fixed;`

I ended up with completely different background css for mobile and desktop, but I've already sunk enough time into this.

My solution:

```
background: url(../images/my-img.jpg) fixed;
background-size: 150%;
background-position-x: 50%, center;
```

Play with bg-size to zoom in / out, then tweak position-x to move it left-right until it feels about right.  I'm sure you can add position-y if you need to tweak the vertical position as well.